# Mouse scroll wheel switches direction per scroll

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, macos

Starting yesterday my third-party Bluetooth mouse keeps changing the scroll direction each time I scroll.
If I scroll down, the screen will move down. Scroll in the same direction to move further down and the screen moves up. And so on like a yo-yo.

- Mouse has enough charge
- Rebooted.
- Power-cycled mouse.
- I did not upgrade my OS in the last week.
- I tried changing the natural scroll setting.
- Dragging the scrollbar works normally

M1 13" laptop, Jellycomb vertical mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I connected an old Logitech mouse with USB transponder and I scrolls correctly. Must be something wrong in the Jellycomb mouse. Will update if I find a solution specific to that device.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue and, if it's the same, it's hardware support related. Trying a different mouse will confirm it.

Are you on Ventura? You can try upgrading. My mouse has been doing the yo-yo less.

Comment: Monterey 12.6. I mentioned that I confirmed the mouse is at root of the problem in my self-answer above. Slightly glad I am not the only one affected.